# Scrollable div with css rollovers = overflow issues

Tags: css, html, overflow, rollover

I'm working on an interface that utilizes a list of items within a scrollable div, some of which utilize a rollover menu on hover that extends outside of the div.  Disabled scripting compatibility is a priority for the site, so I'm trying to see if the interface can be done with only CSS before I start getting into other compromises.

I've got some examples below.  The menu in question is on the right side with heading 'select projects'.  The third list item from the top in each page contains a rollover menu.

In order to keep the rollovers positioned relative to the their parent when scroll position changes, I positioned the parent li's relative and the child ul's positioned absolute.
[EXAMPLE 1](http://eypaedesign.com/markets-rollover-issue-no-overflow.htm)

Of course, once **overflow:auto** is on and the scroll in place, the rollovers are cut off from displaying.
[EXAMPLE 2](http://eypaedesign.com/markets-rollover-issue-scroll.htm)

I tried removing the relative positioning of the parent li's, and retaining the absolute positioning of the rollovers to free them from the div, but then they do not position properly when scroll position is changed.
I can only post two links but if you want an illustration, it's here: eypaedesign.com/markets-rollover-issue-no-relative.htm

With the exception of changing the UI, is there a combination of properties I'm not seeing here that can be used to make this interface work on CSS? I could position the entire div as absolute, and add a large amount of left padding for the rollovers to appear in, but that seems pretty inelegant.

Thanks folks -

Answer (score 2):

With only CSS, you are limited to only one or the other: `overflow: auto` or overflowing hover-menus.  Using separate `visible` and `auto` properties for `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` doesn't work, so I think your best bet is to go with the padding solution you were considering.

With proper use of absolute positioning and `z-index` (in case you are concerned about padded menu container hit-blocking any elements under the padding), you should be able to do it without destroying the rest of your layout.  You'll have to control the size of all child elements inside the scrollable container of course, so that they don't extend to the full width of their padded parent.

Adding these properties - with no other changes - seems to work on your site, so perhaps you can get away with it easily:

```
#project_menu {
  padding-left: 300px;
  margin-left: -300px;
}

.center {
  position: relative;
  z-index; 10;
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of the negative margin idea - I'm going to look into it - a big thank you for sharing that.

Answer (score 0):

if you put a height of 293px in your class nav it should be ok.
Or in you project_menu ID, As I can see that ID has a height of 218px and your UL is 293px.

By changing one of those 2 you should be ok. It depends on how you set it affect other element.

But using project_menu ID should be just good.